# Get rows that have no information between two times without distinct key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with actions that employees perform during a transaction with a customer. There is a certain process they should always follow when performing a transaction.

I'm trying to figure out how to capture the start of a transaction where an employee did not perform the proper steps.

The process should always start with an Action_Taken = 1, end with an Action_Taken = 3, but should have a third (or more) Action_Taken between these two (this Action_taken can equal any number, but could never be 1 or 3 again). The problem comes in when the middle Action is missing and that's what I'm trying to capture.

For Example:

```
Date_time              Employee Action_Taken  Client
2019-10-01 01:21:08.000    1        1           73
2019-10-01 01:30:50.000    1        2           73
2019-10-01 01:46:21.000    1        4           73
2019-10-01 01:52:41.000    1        3           73
2019-10-03 03:24:40.000    2        1           61
2019-10-03 03:53:28.000    2        3           61
2019-10-03 04:29:15.000    2        2           61
2019-10-01 11:43:55.000    3        1           54
2019-10-01 11:47:54.000    3        2           54
2019-10-01 11:52:00.000    3        3           54
2019-10-02 05:36:27.000    1        1           76
2019-10-02 05:59:00.000    1        3           76
2019-10-03 06:18:00.000    2        1           67
2019-10-03 06:25:56.000    2        2           67
2019-10-03 06:34:34.000    2        3           67
```

I expect to get this output which is rows 5 and 11:

```
Date_time              Employee Action_Taken  Client
2019-10-03 03:24:40.000    2        1           61
2019-10-01 01:21:08.000    1        1           73
```

Here is what I've already tried:

```
select *, concat(convert(date, date_time), Employee, client) AS actionkey
into #Trans_Start
from #Table
where Action_Taken = 1


select *,concat(convert(date, date_time), Employee, client) AS actionkey
into #Trans_Actions
from #test
where Action_Taken = 2

select * 
from #Trans_Start as start
where start.actionkey not in (select act.actionkey from #Trans_actions  as act  where act.actionkey = start.actionkey)
```

It is close to what I need and outputs only one row:

```
Date_time              Employee Action_Taken  Client
2019-10-01 01:21:08.000    1        1           73
```

I know it only outputs this row because of the way my actionkey is defined. It is missing because Employee 2 ended up doing an action, but it was with of the wrong sequence(They new their mistake and tried to fix it).

I just can not seem to figure out how to capture a transaction into the table if they ended up posting the action out of the proper sequence.

Any help would be appreciated, it could be a completely different approach than what I took.

Comment: Can the rows for a given "session" be interleaved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not assume that employee/client tuples determine the groups. In the real life, it could probably happen that a given employee serves the same client several times.

Here is an approach that uses solely window functions without aggregation, and that works as follows:

1. build groups of consecutive actions: for a given employee/client, a new group starts everytime action 1 is met.
2. implement the following controls on each group:

   - a group must contain one and only one action 3
   - action 3 must be the last action in the group
   - at least one action other than 1 or 3 must be present in the group
3. Exhibit the first record in each group that fails the checks

Query:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(case when action_taken = 3 then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by employee, client, grp) cnt_3,
        sum(case when action_taken not in (1, 3) then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by employee, client, grp) cnt_others,
        last_value(action_taken) 
            over(partition by employee, client, grp order by employee) last_action
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            sum(case when action_taken = 1 then 1 else 0 end) 
                over(partition by employee, client order by date_time) grp
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
where 
    action_taken = 1
    and not (cnt_3 = 1 and last_action = 3 and cnt_others > 0)
order by employee, client, date_time
```

The most inner subquery does a window sum to identify the groups (`grp`). The next outer query counts how many actions 3 there are in the groups, how many other actions, and retrieves the last action. Finnaly, the outer query filters on the first record per group and on the results of the checks.

In **[this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0fb96a6bda74229419557e3112a87e5)** with your sample data, this returns:

```
Date_time           | Employee | Action_Taken | Client | grp | cnt_3 | cnt_others | last_action
:------------------ | -------: | -----------: | -----: | --: | ----: | ---------: | ----------:
02/10/2019 05:36:27 |        1 |            1 |     76 |   1 |     1 |          0 |           3
03/10/2019 03:24:40 |        2 |            1 |     61 |   1 |     1 |          1 |           2
```

Note that the additional columns in the output also give you the reason why a group was flagged. First record is missing an *other* action, second record has last action 2 instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

The employee/client combinations seem to uniquely define each group.  If this is true, you can identify the groups that have problems using aggregation and having:

```
select employee, client
from t
group by employee, client
having min(date_time) <> max(case when action_taken = 1 then date_time end) or
       max(date_time) <> min(case when action_take = 3 then date_time end) or
       sum(case when action_taken = 1 then 1 else 0 end) <> 1 or
       sum(case when action_taken = 3 then 1 else 0 end) <> 1;
```

You can then incorporate this into a query to get the first members of this group:

```
select t.* 
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employee, client order by date_time) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t join
     (select employee, client
      from t
      group by employee, client
      having min(date_time) <> max(case when action_taken = 1 then date_time end) or
             max(date_time) <> min(case when action_take = 3 then date_time end) or
             sum(case when action_taken = 1 then 1 else 0 end) <> 1 or
             sum(case when action_taken = 3 then 1 else 0 end) <> 1
      ) ec
      on t.employee = ec.employee and t.client = ec.client
where seqnum = 1;
```